# Why do I get 'Error: Converting circular structure to JSON' with a label?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code, verbatim from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag):

```
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 'coconut' };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { options } = event.target;
    console.log(options)
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

As it is, if I try `console.log(options)`, I get the error:

`Error: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

However, moving the `<label>` tag up (so we have):

```
<label>Pick your favorite La Croix flavor:</label>
```

Allows the `console.log()` to work as intended.

Why does moving the label have this effect?

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ao3qce?file=index.js).

Comment: Looks like it comes from stackblitz.com, not your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is an issue with StackBlitz, as the same code works as expected on CodeSandbox and JSFiddle.